# Traversing multiple unordered lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists

Consider the following markup :

```
<div class="col6">
    <h2>Accueil</h2>
    <ul class="listing">
        <li><a href="#" title="bg_home">Accueil</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="bg_homeTakeover">Homepage Takeover</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="bg_homePromoOverlay">Homepage Promo Overlay</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="bg_homeFeatureOverlay">Homepage Feature Overlay</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="bg_homeFeatureScrollOverlay">Homepage Feature Scroll + Takeover</a></li>
    </ul>

    <h2>Thèmes & intégrations</h2>
    <ul class="listing">                        
        <li><a href="#" title="bg_le30">Le 30</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="bg_menuCarte">Menu à la carte</a></li>                           
        <li><a href="#" title="bg_intTheme">Intégration thème</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="bg_intVirtuel01">Intégration papier virtuel 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="bg_intVirtuel02">Intégration papier virtuel 2</a></li>
    </ul>

    <h2>Galeries</h2>
    <ul class="listing">
        <li><a href="#" title="bg_gal01">St-Valentin noir & blanc</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="bg_gal02">Cuisinez avec le fromage</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="bg_gal03">Des fraises pour dessert</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="bg_gal04">Nos meilleures recettes de homard</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="bg_gal05">Jeudi 5@7</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to traverse the uls with my #leftArrow and #rightArrow. I have a page with an overlay and I change the background image with these arrows. However, I'm not able to pass from the first ul to the second an so on when clicking these arrows.

Here's the Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var current_li;
    //OPEN OVERLAY
    $('.innerWrap a').click(function(){

        var src = $(this).attr("title");

        current_li = $(this).parent();

        var text = $(current_li).text();
        $('#frame h2').text(text) 

        $('#projectOverlay').css({'background-image': 'url(img/' + src + '.jpg)' ,});


        $('#frame').fadeIn(400);
        $('#projectOverlay').fadeIn(400);

    })

    //RIGHT
    $("#rightArrow").click(function(){

        if(current_li.is(":last-child")) {                  
            var next_li = current_li.parents('ul').siblings().find('li').first();                                                   
        } else {
            var next_li = current_li.next();            
        }

        var next_src = next_li.children('a').attr("title");            

        current_li = next_li; 
    })

    //LEFT
    $("#leftArrow").click(function(){

        if(current_li.is(":first-child")) {
            //var prev_li = $('.innerWrap ul li').last();
            var prev_li = current_li.parents('ul').siblings().find('li').last();
        } else {
            var prev_li = current_li.prev();
        }

        var prev_src= prev_li.children('a').attr("title");         

        current_li = prev_li;

    })

});
```

Any help would be appreciated !

Thanks !

Comment: Can you strip out the irrelevant jQuery? That's a lot to sift through. You probably just need either left or right, and not both. Also explain more thoroughly what your click function should do.

Comment: Please add information to your question, not in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/rgwst1xj/4/

EDIT: solution

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// I set current_li manually, so change it
var current_li = $('a').first().parent();
// Use your own method to determine which ul is the current one
var current_ul = 0;

//RIGHT
$("#rightArrow").click(function(){

    if(current_li.is(":last-child")) {
        // you may want to be more specific with $('ul').length
        current_ul = (current_ul + 1)%$('ul').length;
        var next_li = current_li.parent().parent().find('ul:eq('+current_ul+')').find('li').first();
    } else {
        var next_li = current_li.next();            
    }

    var next_src = next_li.children('a').attr("title");

    current_li = next_li;

    console.log(current_li.text())
    var text = $(current_li).text();
    $('#frame h2').text(text);  
})

//LEFT
$("#leftArrow").click(function(){

    if(current_li.is(":first-child")) {
        //var prev_li = $('.innerWrap ul li').last();
        current_ul = (current_ul - 1)%$('ul').length;
        var prev_li = current_li.parent().parent().find('ul:eq('+current_ul+')').find('li').last();
    } else {
        var prev_li = current_li.prev();
    }

    var prev_src= prev_li.children('a').attr("title");

    $('#projectOverlay').animate({opacity: 0}, 200, function() {
        $(this)
            .css({'background-image': 'url(img/' + prev_src + '.jpg)' ,})
            .animate({opacity: 1});

            bgSize($('#projectOverlay'), function(width, height){
            $("#frame").css("height",height)                
            $("#projectOverlay").css("height",height);
        });     
     });         

    current_li = prev_li;
    console.log(current_li.text())
    var text = $(current_li).text();
    $('#frame h2').text(text); 

})
});
```

Comment: SO requires that you post your relevant code here, in your answer.

Comment: That's my problem ,It loops in the first and the second ul but not the third.

Comment: i figured out the problem, I'll post a solution in a sec. When in the first ul, the first ul in the siblings is the second ul and when in the second ul, the  first ul in the siblings is the first ul

Comment: Thank you very much ! It worked like a charm and saved me countless hours of work.